# Problems when saving object in LINQ/ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Problems when saving object in LINQ/C#

when i try to save a new record i get this error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EmpresaID', table 'mydb.dbo.Empresa'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Was Made the table with SQL Server Management Studio 2012

```
USE [mydb]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Empresa]    Script Date: 25/04/2012 03:40:00 p.m. ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Empresa]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Empresa]    Script Date: 25/04/2012 03:40:00 p.m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Empresa](
    [EmpresaID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RazonSocial] [nvarchar](210) NOT NULL,
    [Nit] [nchar](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Empresa] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmpresaID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

i made a class for handle the data

```
[Table(Name = "Empresa")]
class Empresa
{
    private int _EmpresaID;
    private string _RazonSocial;
    private string _Nit;

    [Column(DbType = "int", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int EmpresaID
    {
        set { _EmpresaID = value; }
        get { return _EmpresaID; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "nvarchar(210)", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string RazonSocial
    {
        set { _RazonSocial = value; }
        get { return _RazonSocial; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "nchar(20)", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Nit
    {
        set { _Nit = value; }
        get { return _Nit; }
    }

}
```

made and which method is this:

```
Entity.Empresa empresa = new Entity.Empresa() {                
    Nit = NuevaEmpresaNitTxtBox.Text,
    RazonSocial = NuevaEmpresaRazonSocialTxtBox.Text
};

MyDataContext.GetTable<Entity.Empresa>().InsertOnSubmit(empresa);
MyDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

### can tell me was worng with my code?

Comment: You should probably set DbType="Int NOT NULL" on the EmpresaID property since that'd be (more) correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to declare Identity on EmpressaId. :)

Comment: It's really tricky this Management Studio. that problem to modify a table

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping says `EmpresaID` is generated by the database (`IsDbGenerated = true`), however the table definition does not generate ids for the associated table.

You probably want to change the column type of EmpresaID to `IDENTITY` so it will generate primary key values.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the EmpresaID.

Either set it explicitly in your code, or alter your SQL TABLE to add IDENTITY to your EmpresaID column.

Answer (score 1):

You never give an ID for your primary key. There is two solution:

- Give it an explicit ID from your code (you'll need to make sure it's always unique)
- Add the key word IDENTITY on line [EmpresaID] [int] NOT NULL to make your id field an INT IDENTITY that will have a unique value assigned at each insert.